# How to accept hash parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, parameter-passing

Here are the parameters being passed:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"j3R0aro/Arg4Y3Zu6zIIxZYbYTxqoqyKEGc11CkvYDU=",
 "inventory"=>{
   "9"=>"0",
   "12"=>"0",
   "1"=>"0",
   "2"=>"0",
   "3"=>"0",
   "10"=>"0",
   "11"=>"0",
   ...
 }
}
```

I can't seem to grab the params in `inventory`, for whatever reason, the code below keeps wanting to grab the inventory as one long array of hashes rather than the hashes themselves. What am I doing wrong?

```
def inventory_params
  params.permit(inventory: [{:itemlist_id => :quantity}] )
  @inventory_params = params.reject { |k, v| (v == "") || ( v == "0" ) }
end
```

I also tried `params.permit(inventory: {:itemlist_id => :quantity} )` which didn't work either

Comment: By the way this is not an array of hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working:

```
params["inventory"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params.require(:model_name).permit(:inventory)
```

will work I guess.